# Can Twinned Spell be used on Plane Shift when it's used to banish an unwilling creature to another plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, metamagic

[*Plane shift*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift) has two uses:

- to bring yourself and up to 8 more willing creatures to another
  plane, *or*
- to make a melee spell attack against a single unwilling creature, and
  then force it to make a Charisma saving throw or be brought to
  another plane

The [sorcerer's Twinned Spell metamagic option](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#Metamagic) lets you spend sorcery points to affect two creatures with a spell that normally affects only one.

But here, I'm not sure if the second effect of *plane shift* is considered eligible for the Twinned Metamagic, because its first effect can indeed affect more than one creature.

Can Twinned Spell be used on *plane shift* when it's used to banish an unwilling creature to another plane?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No, the errata specifies that spells capable of targetting more than one target do not qualify for twinned spell.

From the errata:

> **Twinned Spell (p. 102).** To be eligible
>   for Twinned Spell, a spell must be incapable
>   of targeting more than one creature at
>   the spell’s current level.

Since part one of the spell can target up to 8 creatures, it's disqualified from being twinned. The option of targetting more is what disqualifies it, which is the same reason you can't twin magic missile if you only target one creature, or eldritch blast when it hits level 5.

Frankly I'd houserule yes if you were just using the 2nd part. But then again I'd also houserule using Magic Missile against one target to be able to be twinned, as well as any other spell that's only hitting one thing. But that's not what the rules say, that's DM privilege.

Comment: Holy cow, that means I mistakenly cheated in AL play... oopsies.

Comment: @GaelL: Everyone makes mistakes - as long as you avoid the error in the future, you're fine :)

Comment: There's an argument to be made that one way to determine if a spell is capable of targeting more than one target is to first pick one target, then see if you could also pick any more targets.  For plane shift, no if they're unwilling.  For magic missile, yes, after you've only picked the target of the first missile.  (But that criterion could allow twin spell due to range reasons, like there not being any valid targets near your first target, for spells that require two nearby targets, or like Mass Cure Wounds or Fireball on two separate targets far from each other, where Twin shouldn't work)